# Setting up an irated integral?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

Using whatever method you like, evaluate the integral $I =\int \int \int_ExdV$ where $E$ is the region between the cylinders $x^2+y^2=1$ and $x^2+y^2=4$, below the plane $z=y+2$ and above the $xy$-plane.

My attemp at setting this up. I make the substitution $dV=dzdydx$ I believe that this is the easiest way. This way I don't have to change the $x$ in the integrand. I get this integral.

$$\int_{?}^?  \int_{?}^?  \int_{?}^? xdzdydx$$

I still have to find the limits of integration. to find $y$ I do some calculations.
$$x^2+y^2=4, x^2+y^2= 1$$
$$x^2=1-y^2, (1-y^2) + y^2=4$$
Solve for $y$
$$(y^2-y^2)+ 1 = 4$$
$$1=4?$$

This does not add up. I am having trouble finding the limits of integration. If anyone can help me that would be great. Thanks

Also can I go this route?

$$dV=dxdydz$$

$$\int_{0}^2  \int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^\sqrt{1-x^2}  \int_{-\sqrt{1-y^2}}^\sqrt{1-y^2} xdxdydz$$

This is another one of my thoughts. Maybe $z$ is a max at 2 because at the $xy$-plane $z=0$ if $y=0$, so just plug $y=0$ into the equation. $z=(0)+2$, then $z=2$
Am I on the right track with this one?

Comment: Those integrals, when the get irated…

Comment: Cylindrical coordinates would be good here.

Comment: In your first set of calculations you have attempted to find points of intersection between $x^2+y^2=1$ and $x^2+y^2=4$. However, these cylinders do not intersect, which is why you are getting a contradictory conclusion.

Comment: Turns out you can graph it. I had a tutor tell me to do it this way. The graph revealed the limits of integration.

Comment: the easiest way is to note that the answer is $0$